# DB Server Requirements Advice

Tags: amazon-ec2, hardware, database-server

I am building a MySQL database with a web front end for a client. The client and their staff will use this webapp on a daily basis, creating anywhere from a few thousand, to possibly a few hundred thousand records annually. I just picked up a second client who wishes to have the same product and will probably be creating the same number of records annually, possibly more.

In the future I hope to pick up a few more clients. In the next few years I could have up to 5 databases & web front ends running for 5 distinct clients, all needing tight security while creating, likely, millions of records annually (cumulatively across all the databases).

I would like to run all of this with Amazon's EC2 service but am having difficulty deciding on what type of instance to run. I am not sure if I should have several distinct Linux instances, one per client, or run one "large" instance which would manage all the clients' databases and web front ends.

I know that hardware configuration is rather specific to the task at hand. The web front ends will be using JQuery to make MySQL queries "pretty" and I will likely be doing some graphing of data (again with JQuery). The front ends will be using SSL for security, which I understand can add some overhead to the network speed.

I'm looking for some of your thoughts on this situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the tools that are available.  The [Amazon RDS service](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) lets you run a MySQL database in the cloud with no extra effort.  You can scale it up and down as you need - start small, and then as you hit your limits, add extra capacity (at extra cost).

Next, use [Elastic Load Balancing (ELB)](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) with an SSL certificate, so you offload the overhead of SSL decryption to an Amazon service.

If you're using Java for your webapp, you could use [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) to handle the whole hosting process for you.

Don't be afraid to experiment - you can always resize instances with no data loss (if they boot from an EBS volume) and you can always create and delete instances.  Scaling horizontally is often better than scaling vertically, as you can spread your instances across multiple Availability Zones.

Good luck!